# How to slice the first column from a conditional output in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The code below prints all of the products that sold 100,000 units. I just want to print the 'title_orig' column values. How can I do this?

Code:

```
clothes.loc[clothes['units_sold'] == 100000]
```

Output:

```
*title_orig*                               *units_sold*
fashion women's strappy top                 100000
women stretchy camisole                     100000
women clothing long sleeve autumn           100000
summer red white and blue chiffon shirt     100000
```

I tried assigning the code to a variable and slicing it but it didn't work.

Comment: try this, `clothes[clothes['units_sold'] == 100000]["title_orig"]`

Comment: ``clothes.loc[clothes['units_sold'] == 100000, 'title_orig']``

Comment: This worked! Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

use `.loc` and pass your desired `column` name:

```
clothes.loc[clothes["units_sold"] == 100000, "title_orig"]
```

should work.